# Specifying virtualenv correctly in uwsgi.conf

Tags: nginx

I am trying to get a uwsgi environment working correctly on Arch, to run my Flask application from a virtualenv.

I have installed uwsgi, nginx and virtualenv and these all work to a point.

However I am seeing the following error in the `uwsgi` log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./interface.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import flask
ImportError: No module named flask
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
unable to find "application" callable in file index.py
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 4795)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 4796, cores: 1)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 4796|app: -1|req: -1/1] 192.168.9.201 () {40 vars in 664 bytes} [Thu Dec 26 08:01:56 2013] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

This indicates that it can't load the flask module, which I am guessing is due to an incorrect `uwsgi.conf`:

```
[uwsgi]
uid = http
gid = http
plugin = python2
socket = %drun/%n.sock
chdir = /srv/http/example/htdocs
master = True
pidfile = %drun/%n.pid
logto = %dlog/%n.log
venv = /srv/http/example/htdocs
pyhome = /srv/http/example/htdocs
module = interface
callable = my_app
no-site = true
```

**Can anyone tell me what I should be setting `venv` and `pyhome` to, as I think this is where the problem lies?  Or in fact if I should be setting both?**

Also relevant, is when I run the following from a terminal, I can import the flask module without errors:

```
$ pwd
/srv/http/example/htdocs
$ . bin/activate
(htdocs) $ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 26 2013, 12:52:49) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask
>>>
```

**Am I just setting `venv` in `uwsgi.conf` incorrectly?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should get rid of `no-site`.  According to the documentation:

> Do not import the site module while initializing Python. This is usually only required for dynamic virtualenvs. **If in doubt, do not enable**.

Also, `pyhome` is an alias for `venv` so you'd be better getting rid of it.

Just for future reference, `venv` should be set to the top level folder of your virtualenv: `/srv/http/example/htdocs`

Comment: Perfect, removal of these two variables (specifically `nosite` I'm guessing) has fixed this.